# Starting container process caused: exec: "entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an `entrypoint.sh` file which I used to start my backend, unfortunately I get an error as the title above.

My root directory
[image]

My backend directory (the service that gets failed to be built)
[image]

my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DB_USER}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Edit #1 backend dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine3.14
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
    python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . /code/
RUN chmod u+x ./entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Please, post your docker file.

Comment: Also, the `volumes:` block in the `backend` container will overwrite the image's `/code` directory with content from your host, possibly a completely different application from what the image builds.  If the Dockerfile does things like correct the line ending or permissions of the file, the `volumes:` block will cause this to be lost.  You can usually safely remove this block.

Comment: Added dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

the command should be noted with an absolute path in the container

or with ./ if its in the working dir in the container.

if you write it as you did it needs to be in the PATH. usually in one of theses folders : /bin, /usr/bin, etc

Comment: So I replaced this `command: /code/entrypoint.sh` with what I had earlier but for the `db` it says my database doesn't exist and my `backend` says `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.18.0.3", user "vostok1forrestgump", database "hackerreviews", SSL off`